# ReactJS: Link to go to next page dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this App.jsx that has the routing and I have a component NextPage.jsx that is a simple Link that should point to the next page. My issue is:how can I tell to the link in NextPage component to point to the next page? so if I am in Homepage the link should let me go to Portfolio, if on Portfolio I should be able to go to Skills and so on.

This is my App.jsx

```
const App = () => (
  <div className="main-container">
    <Menu/>
    <NextPage/>
    <AnimatedSwitch
      atEnter={{ offset: 100}}
      atLeave={{ offset: -100}}
      atActive={{offset: 0}}
      mapStyles={(style) => ({
        transform: `translateX(${style.offset}%)`,
      })}
    >
      <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
      <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
      <Route path="/skills" component={Skills} />
      <Route path="/contacts" component={Contacts} />
      <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
    </AnimatedSwitch>
  </div>  
);

export default App;
```

This is my NextPage.jsx

```
const NextPage = () => (
        <div className="next-arrow">
          <Link to='#HEREGOESTHENEXTPAGELINK#'><i className="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></Link>
        </div>
    );

export default NextPage;
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You just want a link in `NextPage` that takes you to `Skills`? If so, just edit your Link to be: `<Link to ='/skills'>...`

Comment: Nope, the Link in NextPage must send you to the next page, so for example if I'm in Homepage the link should send me to Portfolio, if I'm in the Portfolio page the link should send me to Skills and so on

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to implementing this seems a bit odd in my opinion, but I digress.

The first thing you'd need to do is to somehow store all the links as well as their order of appearance. The biggest question I'd say is *where* you're going to store this; you could store it in a database, create a global variable, store it in a stage-management library (if you use one), etc etc.

It is unclear which of these you use and which you'd prefer, so I'll leave that to you and just present the concept below.

---

In your root React Component define an array of all the links. You could do this in the constructor:

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    window.links = ["/", "/portfolio", "/skills", "/contacts"];
  }

  render() ...
}
```

This will make `window.links` accessible in all components. This means you compare the active url, look it up in the array, and make the link direct you to the next one.

```
const NextPage = (props) => {
  let idx = window.links.indexOf(props.route.path) + 1;
  let link = (idx == window.links.length) ? window.links[0] : window.links[idx];
  return (
    <div className="next-arrow">
      <Link to={link}><i className="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NextPage;
```

Note that if the current link is not one of the ones defined in `window.links`, the link will take you to the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, You said it looks a odd way to do it, and well I was actually trying to find the best way or the more functional way to do a simple link to the next page writing just one simple component instead of rendering a link for every single page. So I am totally open to suggestion on how to do it in the best way :)

Comment: @Moae84, it's hard to give any solid suggestion without understanding exactly what you are trying to do. But do look up "subroutes" for react-router. That might be a more suitable solution.

Comment: If this solved your question please consider marking it as "accepted" and/or giving it your vote.

Comment: Is there any way to send props to the NextPage component? if I set something like '<Route path="/" nextpage="/portfolio" component={Homepage}/>

Comment: I have a little issue with your solution, on this line `  let idx = window.links.indexOf(this.props.route.path) + 1;` the console show me an Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'props' of udnefined

Comment: @Moae84, oh sorry. I missed the fact that you made a stateless functional component! Will update the answer.

Comment: this time it cannot read 'path" of undefined 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the output of `console.log(this.props)` and post it here?

Comment: here the screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bya7aIlk22beUU45QTNNbWtTMTg